# Raycast not smooth after hit position (ground to road)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm new to *Geometry Nodes*... I'm making a road on the contoured ground. I want a road higher than the ground. I used the *Raycast* node to make it but it's not natural. The ground is too stiff as the example image below shows.

[image: not smooth]

[image: NO edges on faces]

[image: geonodes]

[File Blender 3.3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dC4kGPUxjX-XcS310BOeHeXapKumSRKQ/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Hi Hendra, If I wanted to have help from others who like to help in their spare time - i would make it as easy as possible to attract more people. E.g. by providing blend file so they don't have to rebuild everything on their own.

Comment: @hendra As Chris suggests, you should probably share your file. You can use blend-exchange.com to get the share code and edit it into your question. Also, I'm not exactly sure what you want. What does "NOT EDGES" mean? Do you want your road to fly *above* your topography? You want the topography to gently slope up towards it instead of making sudden cliffs on its sides...?

Comment: @Kuboå "You want the topography to gently slope up towards it instead of making sudden cliffs on its sides...?"  (yes)

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you would like to have more subdivisions in the vertically running geometry, right? Unfortunately, you can't solve that with Geometry Nodes. For that, you would have to edit the mesh in Edit Mode accordingly, since Geometry Nodes unfortunately does not provide selective subdivision. However, you may be able to (awkwardly) create additional geometry at the edge with `Extrude Mesh`, which you move downwards to the raycast target. Would this be a solution for you (even if it would not be very procedural)?

Comment: ''As far as I understand your question, you would like to have more subdivisions in the vertically running geometry, right?'' (yes) and i want to slope + noise ,@quellenform

Comment: OK, I understand, then I'm afraid you won't be happy with *Geometry Nodes* in this case. There are possibilities, but the result would be too unpredictable and would require manual post-processing. My recommendation: Convert to a mesh, and post-process in *Edit Mode* or with sculpting.